# Refreshing UI after parallel processings completion

Tags: android, rx-android

I try to use RxAndroid in my app and I'm stuck for a while on this problem.

I want to update each list object with the result of a webservice call and when this processing is done for each, I want to refresh a recyclerview.

```
OLSLog.v("refreshDistancesFromUser");
Observable.from(mListInterventions).map(this::updateDistanceFromUser).subscribe(new Observer<Subscription>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {
                                OLSLog.v("onCompleted");
                                // refresh recyclerview
                            }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Subscription pSubscription) {

                        }
                    });

private Subscription updateDistanceFromUser(GMIntervention pIntervention) {
        return WSFacade.getRoutes(mUserLocation.getLatitude(), mUserLocation.getLongitude(), pIntervention.getSite()
            .getLatitude(), pIntervention.getSite().getLongitude()).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe
                (pResponseDto -> {
            Long vDistance = pResponseDto.getListRoutes().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDistance().getValue();
            Long vDuration = pResponseDto.getListRoutes().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDuration().getValue();
            OLSLog.d("distance from user: " + vDistance);
            pIntervention.setDistanceFromUser(new GMDistanceFrom(vDistance, vDuration));
        }, pThrowable -> OLSLog.e("fail to get directions", pThrowable));
    }
```

My problem is onCompleted() is called when processing of the last list object is launched not when all processings are completed.

```
05-25 16:44:00.254 V/### HomeActivity: refreshDistancesFromUser
05-25 16:44:00.282 D/OkHttp: --> GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json http/1.1
05-25 16:44:00.288 V/### HomeActivity$1: onCompleted
05-25 16:44:00.296 D/OkHttp: --> GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json? http/1.1
05-25 16:44:00.301 D/OkHttp: --> GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json http/1.1
05-25 16:44:00.969 D/OkHttp: <-- 200  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json (668ms, unknown-length body)
05-25 16:44:00.977 D/OkHttp: <-- 200  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json (680ms, unknown-length body)
05-25 16:44:00.981 D/OkHttp: <-- 200  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json (698ms, unknown-length body)
05-25 16:44:00.990 D/### HomeActivity: distance from user: 7320
05-25 16:44:00.991 D/### HomeActivity: distance from user: 17387
05-25 16:44:00.992 D/### HomeActivity: distance from user: 2753
```

How can I "wait" all updateDistanceFromUser() processings are really "completed" to refresh my recyclerview?

Thanks.

Comment: what is updateDistanceFromUser? Your service call?

Comment: Yes, it is. I had it in my previous post.

Comment: Do you read anything from `mListInterventions`? Because it looks like you just write to it.

Comment: For the wait question, you're just waiting for Observable.from, which completes immediately. If you give me more info, I can help you more.

Comment: I would like Observable.from completes when all updateDistanceFromUser() calls are completed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mapping input to subscriptions which are created instantaneously and then returned one by one.
You can combine those observables so that you receive results in the same stream.

One operator that could help you is [Merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html).

Comment: No sure to understand how to do: in my case, Observables to merge don't have same <T> (GMIntervention vs WSCallResult), any example in this case would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not subscribe while inside map or similar operators, that defeats the purpose or RxJava.

I would use `flatMap` to turn your `Observable<GMIntervention>` into `Observable<ResponseDto>`. You might need `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` if `WSFacade.getRoutes` is synchronous.

If you want to do everything correctly, only publish your results to the UI inside the `Subscriber` methods. That will be a bit more complicated.

Edit: You should check out [Grokking RxJava](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1/) if you're new to it.

Comment: I read it and I already tried flatMap() but when I subscribe to Observable<ResponseDto>, is it possible and if, how can I access to relative GMIntervention to update it?

Comment: I would like to do something like that but it is not possible: Observable.from(mListInterventions).flatMap(vIntervention -> getDistanceFromUser(vIntervention))
                    .subscribe(pResponseDto -> {
                        Long vDistance = pResponseDto.getListRoutes().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDistance().getValue();
                        Long vDuration = pResponseDto.getListRoutes().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDuration().getValue();
                        vIntervention.setDistanceFromUser(new GMDistanceFrom(vDistance, vDuration));
                    });